# nginx: all traffic to index.php

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How can I send all traffic to a single index.php file regardless of path or domain?  What is the fastest way to do this in nginx.conf? try_files?

Thanks for insight

Answer (score 2):

```
# Assuming you want static files as well
server {
    listen 80 default_server; # Use default; instead if you're still on 0.7.x.
    try_files $uri /index.php;

    # Standard PHP location block here.
}

# Assuming you do not want static files as well
server {
    listen 80 default_server; # Use default; instead if you're still on 0.7.x.
    location = /index.php {
        # Fastcgi/proxy pass
    }

    location / {
            rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }
}
```

Comment: could be a bit more specific in you example? :)

Answer (score 0):

First answer that came to mind, i suppose you can put this wherever it benefits you the most.

```
rewrite .* /index.php;
```

Comment: Ok thanks but where would I put this?  I want literally everything to go to index.php (error pages, directories that don't exist)